# Elm - Unable to find a set of packages that will work with your constraints

Tags: elm

Getting this error with Elm. On a Mac with Elm 0.17. Any suggestions? I blew up the elm-stuff folder and tried again. Same thing. Can't seem to get rid of this. I am very new to elm.

```
$ elm-repl
---- elm repl 0.17.0 -----------------------------------------------------------
 :help for help, :exit to exit, more at <https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-repl>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 2 + 2
Unable to find a set of packages that will work with your constraints.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was an elm-package.json in the same folder. I had to blow it up as well and then the repl started working again. Hope this helps someone else.